# More important... or more importantly?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Why am I so bothered when a topic is being explained, the speaker interrupts the flow and inserts "but more importantly..."  This usage is very, very common. But is it consistent with English grammar? My inclination would be to say "but more important..." and then proceed to explain what I wish to insert. Am I incorrect?

Comment: Depends on the context and what grammatical role either is playing in that context. Either can be correct.

Comment: Good find @EdwinAshworth Therefore the OP can feel free to use *more important* at least on the basis that one Hahvahd publication uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the term 'pragmatic marker', but the classical term 'sentence adverb' shows that the -ly form is standard. 'First' rather than 'firstly' may be used, and 'Doubtless, you're the man' shows an accepted but I'd say old-fashioned usage. I myself wouldn't use 'But more important,' in place of the sentence adverbial / pragmatic marker (showing speaker evaluation) 'But more importantly,'.

*Hovever*:

Amazingly, an example of 'More important' rather than 'More importantly' being the chosen form occurs (but not as an example!) in this article from Harvard University: [I.3 Approaches to particles and discourse markers](https://chs.harvard.edu/CHS/article/display/6201.i-3-approaches-to-particles-and-discourse-markers#noteref_n.92):

> §63. ... Conversation Analysis has received less attention so far.
>   [92] More important, many classicists use a generally pragmatic
>   approach. That is, they pay attention to the linguistic and
>   extralinguistic context of a passage: ...

This find has prompted me to check on possible acceptable pragmatic marker usage.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doubtless) licenses both

> **doubtless** ADVERB 1 sentence adverb
>
> Certainly; without doubt. ...
>
> 1.1 Presumably or very probably. ‘doubtless you'll solve the problem’

and

> **[more] important**
>
> sentence adverb: ‘the speech had passion and, more important,
>   compassion’

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/important)]

Comment: Okay, since you have made your comment an answer, I'll copy my coment to here: Good find @EdwinAshworth Therefore the OP can feel free to use *more important* at least on the basis that one Hahvahd publication uses it. More important(ly), I'll add that the subject of [flat adverbs](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/) is probably a related one.

Comment: Flat adverbs are usually central adverbs (modifying the verb), but can have semantic idiosyncrasies.  Contrast 'We flew direct/directly to Cairo'.